# How do I define a vector where the first element isn't n= 0?

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I am trying to convolve two vectors in discrete time. Numerically I am getting the correct answer however when I plot them with a stem plot I cant find a way to show that n starts at `-3` and not `0`.
For example,

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6];
h = [-1 0 1];
y = conv(x,h);
n = [-3;5]
stem(n,y)
```

will output a stem plot that starts at n=0.
I want the stem plot to start at `n=-3`.
The `n=0` index of `x` is at the `value(2)`, however Matlab thinks the `n=0` index of `x` is at the `value(0)`.

All that I could find is the command `circshift`, which is not what I want.

Comment: This question is confusing in a couple of ways: 1. Matlab arrays start with index 1 not 0, so the premise of your question seems very strange since you seem to be specific that the error has to do with Matlab indexing from 0. 2. It's not really clear what you want to accomplish - Do you for some reason want to be able to have something like `y(-1)` accepted as an indexed value in an array or do you just want to change the labeling on a graph?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
n = [-3;5]
```

with:

```
n=linspace(-3,5,length(y));
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a [`;`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-46) in `n = [-3;5];` you need to use [`:`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html). This will create a range from `-3` to `5`. That is, it should be

```
n = -3:5;
```

which will produce

[image: Plot]

---

The semicolon, [`;`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-46), is used to create a matrix. It allows you to create a new row so

```
>> n = [-3;5]
n =
    -3
     5
```

is a matrix with `2` rows and `1` column. Whilst the colon, [`:`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html), is used to create a range

```
>> n = -3:5
n =
    -3    -2    -1     0     1     2     3     4     5
```